# Solving a problem in Coordinate Geometry

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Suppose,  $2x \cos \alpha - 3y \sin \alpha = 6$ is equation of a variable straight line. From two point $A(\sqrt{5},0$) and  $B(-\sqrt{5},0)$ foot of the altitude on that straight line is $P$ and $Q$ respectively. Show that the product of the length of two line segment $AP$ and $BQ$ is free of $\alpha$.

This question appeared in my exam today. The way I did it is first constructed the equation of two perpendicular line to $2x \cos \alpha - 3y \sin \alpha = 6$ which goes through the points $A(\sqrt{5},0$) and  $B(-\sqrt{5},0)$. In this way, for $A$ and $B$, I got the following equations respectively-
$$3x \sin \alpha + 2y \cos \alpha -3 \sqrt{5}\sin \alpha=0 \qquad(1)$$$$3x \sin \alpha + 2y \cos \alpha +3 \sqrt{5}\sin \alpha=0 \qquad(2)$$

Then I found that the line $(1)$ intersects the line $2x \cos \alpha - 3y \sin \alpha = 6$ at point $$P\left ( \frac{9\sqrt5 \sin^2 \alpha+12 \cos \alpha}{4 \cos^2 \alpha + 9 \sin^2 \alpha}, \frac{-18 \sin \alpha+6\sqrt{5} \sin \alpha \cos \alpha}{4 \cos^2 \alpha + 9 \sin^2 \alpha} \right )$$
and the line $(2)$ intersects the line $2x \cos \alpha - 3y \sin \alpha = 6$ at point $$Q\left ( \frac{-9\sqrt5 \sin^2 \alpha+12 \cos \alpha}{4 \cos^2 \alpha + 9 \sin^2 \alpha}, \frac{-18 \sin \alpha-6\sqrt{5} \sin \alpha \cos \alpha}{4 \cos^2 \alpha + 9 \sin^2 \alpha} \right )$$

Now using distance formula $$AP = \sqrt{ \left ( \frac{9\sqrt5 \sin^2 \alpha+12 \cos \alpha}{4 \cos^2 \alpha + 9 \sin^2 \alpha}- \sqrt5 \right )^2 + \left ( \frac{-18 \sin \alpha+6\sqrt{5} \sin \alpha \cos \alpha}{4 \cos^2 \alpha + 9 \sin^2 \alpha} \right )^2}$$ and $$ BQ= \sqrt{ \left ( \frac{-9\sqrt5 \sin^2 \alpha+12 \cos \alpha}{4 \cos^2 \alpha + 9 \sin^2 \alpha} +\sqrt5 \right )^2 + \left ( \frac{-18 \sin \alpha-6\sqrt{5} \sin \alpha \cos \alpha}{4 \cos^2 \alpha + 9 \sin^2 \alpha} \right )^2}$$

Now the multiplication product $AP \cdot BQ$ indeed gives a constant value of $4$ which is free of the arbitrary variable $\alpha$ as you can [see](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=%5C%2840%29-4+%2B+Divide%5B%5C%2840%2948+%5C%2840%29-3+%2B+sqrt%5C%2840%295%5C%2841%29+cos%5C%2840%29y%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2C%5C%2840%29-13+%2B+5+cos%5C%2840%292+y%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29-4+%2B+Divide%5B%5C%2840%2948+%5C%2840%293+%2B+sqrt%5C%2840%295%5C%2841%29+cos%5C%2840%29y%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2C%5C%2840%2913+-+5+cos%5C%2840%292+y%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%5D%5C%2841%29) here is the simplified version of product of those two quantity. But this is tedious and I do not think this is the only way to do it and an appropriate way to follow in exam with limited time. So, I am looking for an alternative, time saving proof of it. I was wondering if using parametric form would help me, but I think it would get as difficult equally.

I created a [visualisation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/un3kzmqqyo) for you on desmos to help my problem understand better.

Comment: Distance of a point from a line has a neat formula: https://www.cuemath.com/geometry/distance-of-a-point-from-a-line/

Comment: @Aditya_math, is this the only alternative easy way?

Comment: Off topic query: Are you a JEE aspirant?

Comment: @RiverX15, I live in Bangladesh but you can say that I am a (sort of) JEE aspirant because in Bangladesh we give a similar examination for admission in engineering universities and I am on the verge of giving that exam.

Answer (score 2):

Well I have another solution which is very helpful for exams based on mcq pattern, like the one we give it in india.
I have learnt and derived a property in conic sections which says that in a ellipse, the product of perpendiculars from both foci of ellipse to tangent is equal to b$^2$ ,b is semi minor axis.
equation of a general ellipse is

---

$\frac{x^2}{a^2}$ + $\frac{y^2}{b^2}$=1

---

it's tangent equation is-

---

$\frac{xx1}{a^2}$ + $\frac{yy1}{b^2}$=1 (x1 and y1 are points on ellipse, which is taken x1=acos$\phi$ and y1=bsin$\phi$)

---

now tangents is revolving will all possible slopes around ellipse...now to ease our work assume slope =o for a tangent... $\alpha$ in your equation will be $\pi$/2 for zero slope with y intercept +2 or-2
.put that in your equation and find the product of perpendiculars, as line is horizontal ,perpendicular will be of  of equal length. you will find it to be 4.
now as I told product of perpendiculars is $b^2$, so b=2 ,now use that general tangent equation and given equation to find value of a=3.you will see that it satisfies the equation and a ellipse. It means we were assuming it right. The parameter in your equation was making the arbitrary line a tangent to ellipse.
Here is illustration for better understanding
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOinq.png)

Comment: +1 for the geometric insight. Ways to improve the image: (1) add a second, slanted tangent ans append that the distances to it have the same product as you drew with the horizontal tangent; (2) add the circle on which P and Q are known to lie (see my answer). This has a diameter matching the major axis of the ellipse.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Well I think the question has been solved, the circle you are talking about is the auxiliary circle. Now it is the beauty of geometry that someone can still solve it with a little different interpretation .Rest when I solved it as a ellipse I understood every aspect why product is coming out to be constant, I have not written too much equations, but I have written the conclusion. I want the solver to that himself else they won't understand what happening in the question. It's a really good question fro visualization. Rest I agree auxiliary circle will  solve this.

Answer (score 1):

$ \displaystyle 2x \cos \alpha - 3y \sin \alpha = 6 \implies y = \frac{2 \cot \alpha}{3} x - 2 \csc \alpha = mx + c$ where $m = \tan \theta = \dfrac{2 \cot \alpha}{3}$

Consider $0 \leq \alpha \leq 2\pi$ that gives all possible lines for the given equation. If $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\frac{3 \pi}{2}$, the line is $y = -2$ or $y = 2$ respectively and the perp distance from both points on x-axis would be $2$. So the product is $4$. For other values of $\alpha$

The line intersects x-axis at $~ \displaystyle x = \frac{3}{\cos\alpha}$

So distance of the given points to the intersection point is,

$ \left|\displaystyle \sqrt5 \pm \frac{3}{\cos\alpha}\right|$

The product of perpendicular lengths to the line is then given by,

$ \displaystyle \left| 5 - \frac{9}{\cos^2\alpha}\right| \cdot \sin^2\theta = \left| \frac{5 \cos^2\alpha - 9}{\cos^2\alpha} \cdot \frac{\tan^2\theta}{1 + \tan^2\theta} \right|$

Now, $ \displaystyle \frac{\tan^2\theta}{1 + \tan^2\theta} = \frac{4 \cot^2\alpha}{9 + 4 \cot^2\alpha} = \frac{4 \cos^2\alpha}{9 \sin^2\alpha + 4 \cos^2\alpha}$

$ \displaystyle = \frac{4 \cos^2\alpha}{9 - 5 \cos^2\alpha}$

That leads to product being $4$.

Comment: Nice answer +1. However, your method follows the same trail as in @ashank's first answer to somewhat misinterpreted version of this question.

Comment: @BlueBAT my first idea was to just multiply the lengths using the perp distance formula but given both points were on x-axis, I knew this method would not be too tedious either. In fact both methods seem to work fine but I decided to post this over the other.

Answer (score 1):

One missing factor is the locus of points $P$ and $Q$.

For point P we have the system of equations

$2\cos\alpha x - 3\sin\alpha y=6$

$3\sin\alpha x + 2\cos\alpha y=3\sqrt5\sin\alpha$

Square both equations and add. Cross-product terms cancel and we end with

$(4\cos^2\alpha+9\sin^2\alpha)(x^2+y^2)=36+45\sin^2\alpha$

Eliminate $\cos\alpha$ using $\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha=1$, then

$(4+5\sin^2\alpha)(x^2+y^2)=36+45\sin^2\alpha$

$\color{blue}{x^2+y^2=9, \text{ a circle of radius 3}}$

Similarly $Q$ has this same locus.

We then draw this circle which intersects the $x$-axis at $C=(3,0)$ and $D=(-3,0)$. With this in hand we extend $\overline{AP}$ through $A$ to point $Q'$. By symmetry $AQ'=BQ$ (the lines $\overline{AP},\overline{BQ}$ are parallel and equidistant from the center, so $Q$ and $Q'$ are antipodes on the circle). At the same time for intersecting chords of a circle $(AP)(AQ')=(AC)(AD)$. So:

$(AP)(BQ)=(AP)(AQ')=(AC)(AD)=(3-\sqrt5)(3+\sqrt5)=4.$

---

This exercise illustrates a  theorem from the geometry of conic sections. Given an ellipse or a hyperbola, we can drop a perpendicular from both foci to any tangent of the conic. The product of the altitudes will then be the square of the semiminor axis for an ellipse or the square of the semiconjugate axis for a hyperbola. We may interpret the latter case as presenting a negative product (the square of a pure imaginary semiminor axis) because the altitudes are oppositely oriented as if one of them were negative. The family of lines in the problem at hand are the tangents to an ellipse whose vertices are $(\pm3,0)$ (matching a diameter of the circular locus) with foci at the same points as those chosen for $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Modified version of my [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6nwz3xbg4v) makes the symmetry part vivid.

Answer (score -1):

Check out my analysis of your question.
Equation is **2xcosα−3ysinα=0**. This equation passes through origin and points A and B are on x axis. Assume slope of equation be tan $\phi$.

---

[I have illustrated the diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzoE5.png)

---

now product of length of two perpendiculars will be 5 sin$^2$ $\phi$. From equation of line slope of line is $$tan\phi =\frac{2cos\alpha}{3sin\alpha}$$

---

get value of $sin^2\phi$ from $tan\phi$. You will see it is not free of alpha.You can see that in graph too [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s4dcjh6qju)  (I have updated it). As graph is symmetrical ,length will depend on $\phi$.
Maybe I interpreted the question incorrectly. Correct me if it's wrong

Comment: Thanks for your time, Ashank. I am sorry, my equation was $2x \cosα−3y \sinα=6$. You used my desmos [visual](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/un3kzmqqyo) but edited and made it the wrong equation. However, I wasn't the person to -1 your answer. Appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Not a big deal. Then it can be free of alpha. But you can use my method to get an easy solution . I always keep this method as a last option "of finding points and solving problems", it's always lengthy. Do it yourself once ...it seems it won't work because this time distance on x axis is changing ,anyways try it

Comment: Yes, I used your method and it worked. Your method was nice, Thank you. I think giving +1 to your answer would make you feel a bit better and let go of the idea of wasting time.

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYlth.png) image might be helpful in the general case, where $AP\cdot BQ=AX\cdot BX\cdot \sin^2\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle made by the given line with $+X$ axis.

Comment: @RiverX15, thanks for pointing out. I also did it the same way you did.